# Relative Velocity (Kinematics)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, relative-motion

I was studying the concept of relative velocity and after solving a few problems I am running into this confusion.

a) Let’s say two cars are moving perpendicular to each other (no collision) with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ with respect to ground. To calculate the relative velocity should I take the velocities in the direction of motion of cars (OR) should I take the component of velocities along the line joining the two cars?

b) What if the cars are perpendicular and in line with each other initially at a distance $d$ and one of the car starts to chase the other car. How do I take the relative velocity now?

Please make necessary assumptions to answer.

Comment: We have $\vec v_a = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec v_b = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}$ from your definition. The relative velocity of A wrt B will be $\vec v_{AB} = \vec v_a - \vec v_b \to \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix} \to \vec v_{AB} = \begin{pmatrix} v_1 \\ - v_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and velocity of B wrt A will be $-\vec v_{AB} \to \begin{pmatrix} -v_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3):

The velocities are vectors.  The relative velocity is the vector  difference  between the velocities of the two cars.  This covers all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

In any coordinate system, the relative velocity of car 2 w.r.t to car 1 is:

$$\vec v_{rel}=\vec v_2 - \vec v_1 $$

To show this, transform to the frame of car 1 with the transformation:

$$ \vec v' \rightarrow \vec v - \vec v_1 $$

so that:

$$ \vec v'_1 \rightarrow \vec v_1 - \vec v_1 = 0$$
$$ \vec v'_2 \rightarrow \vec v_2 - \vec v_1 = \vec v_{rel}$$